# How to "track" user not authenticated in asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to be able to "track" not-identicated users from server side (keep user preferences such as lang or last search and generate the pages accordingly).

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Are there some built-in features on ASP.Net Core?

I tried to check the User property, but it does not seem to be useful when the user is not logged in.

Comment: You could use a [Cookie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39771683/1070496) or a [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state).  Do you want this tracking information to persist for a long time, or just when they're on the site? (ie. Cookie vs. Session)

Comment: I guess the longest is better for lang choices, so cookies, but are cookies passed to all requests? What about AJAX queries? I am not really familiar to how cookies are handled ^^ But that is what I thought.
I would like to store the lang, and potentially a guid to flag if the user is a new user or not (for statistics)

Comment: Cookies are sent on all requests, AJAX as well. The browser takes care of it. But they are not reliable storage of course, if the user uses e.g. Incognito mode the cookies will be gone the next time.